# CRC32 - different results in PHP vs Java

Tags: java, php, crc32

I have an existing Java code that calculates CRC32 on the first 25MB of a file:

```
            File file = new File(filepath);
            fileLength = file.length();

            FileInputStream fileHandle = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            CheckedInputStream checkedHandle = new CheckedInputStream(fileHandle, new CRC32());
            BufferedInputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(checkedHandle);

            if (fileLength <= 25 * 1024 * 1024) {
                while (bufferedIn.read() != -1) {}
                firstChecksum = checkedHandle.getChecksum().getValue();
            } else {
                byte[] b = new byte[25 * 1024 * 1024]; // 25mb
                while (bufferedIn.read(b) >= 0) {}
                firstChecksum = checkedHandle.getChecksum().getValue();
                checkedHandle.close();
                bufferedIn.close();
                fileHandle.close();
            }
```

We are trying to implement the same function in PHP.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
<?php
$block = 25*1024*1024;
$filesize = filesize("test.mp4");
$in = fopen("test.mp4","r");
$firstblock = fread($in,$block);
fclose($in);
$checksum = crc32($firstblock);
printf("%u\n", $checksum);
?>
```

I am getting different results however.   Java returns 1706882279 while PHP returns 1015401640.   I'm not sure whats going wrong.

I've also tried the php hash() function with crc32 and crc32b and still different results from the Java code.

Can anyone tell what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try with smaller data? If yes, how was the result?

Comment: You might try `"rb"` instead of `"r"`.

Comment: I tried with an 11MB file and still got differing results.   Also, using r vs rb both produced the same results.   After discussing with other staff, we've decided to recheck everything with sha256 instead and replace all the values going forward, so it's no longer an issue for us, but yet it's still a mystery.